# React hooks - Update item in list after edit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, crud

I'm new to React Hooks. I am trying to make a small crud app, with add, edit, delete.
I have some issues getting my edit function to work. When I click the edit, the input will add the values of the element that is clicked. But how do I update the item?

```
const [items, setItems] = useState<any>([]);
const [comment, setComment] = useState("");
const [amount, setAmount] = useState("");

const handleAddSubmit = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newItem = {
        id: new Date().getTime(),
        comment: comment,
        amount: amount,
        preview: preview
    }
    setItems([...items].concat(newItem));

    setFile(null);
    setComment("");
    setAmount("");
};

 const editItem = (item: any) => {
    setFile(undefined);
    setComment(item.comment);
    setAmount(item.amount);
};

const deleteItem = (id: any) => {
    const updatedItems = [...items].filter((item) => item.id !== id);

    setItems(updatedItems);
}

return (
       <div>
        {items.map((item: any, index: any) => {
                return (
                    <div key={item.id}>
                        <div>{item.comment}</div>
                        <div>{item.amount} $</div>
                        <div onClick={() => editItem(item)}>Edit</div>
                        <div onClick={(e) => deleteItem(item.id)}>Delete</div>
                    </div>
                );
            })}

               <input
                value={comment}
                onChange={(e) => setComment(e.target.value)}
                placeholder="Comment"
            />
            <input
                value={amount}
                onChange={(e) => setAmount(e.target.value)}
                type="number"
            />
            <button formAction="submit">Add</button>
        </div>
```

)

Comment: can you post the whole code to the sandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So acc to your code when you click on the edit button, this function gets triggered

```
const editItem = (item: any) => {
    setFile(undefined);
    setComment(item.comment);
    setAmount(item.amount);
};
```

Now this function is updating the state and inside the input tags you are using the state as values, so this is the reason why you are getting the results you are getting

Now you can change your code to

```
const editItem = (item) => {
     setItems(items.map(i => i.id === item.id ? {...i, comment, amount} : i);
    setComment("");
    setAmount("");
};
```

Comment: Thank you!
How can I then change the button to another button, with some different text.
Maybe like "Update"?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to say , I'm a bit confused

Comment: So when I click the "edit" button, I can begin to edit, that works fine. 
But I want the button text to change to ex. "Update".
 <div onClick={() => editItem(item)}>Update</div>

Comment: <div onClick={() => editItem(item)}>{item.buttonLabel}</div>   and when you will click on it editItem function will run  setItems(items.map(i => i.id === item.id ? {...i, comment, amount, buttonLabel: "Updated"} : i);   , but remember one thing every item in your items array should have a buttonLabel : "Edit" property

Comment: Did it worked like you expected it too ?

Comment: It did thank you. I have one more question, how do I add an active class, on the element that is being edited?

Comment: I've upvoted your answer :)
The active class, is it possible to make it outside the button, because item.buttonLabel. won't work. The active class is outside the .map function. And on the parent

Comment: Thanks, appreciate that but your active class problem is resolved or not?

Comment: It is not, I want to add active class outside the map function. So your code won't work in my code

Answer (score 3):

You can use a map to go through each element of a list and create a new object for the item you want to update:

```
const editItem = (item) => {
  setItems(items.map(i => i.id === item.id
    ? {...i, comment, amount}
    : i);
  setComment("");
  setAmount("");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
But it still just adds a new item to the list

Comment: A map does not change the length of a list. It's an n->n list transformation function.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just forgot to add an onclick handler to the button:

```
  <button formAction="submit" onClick={handleAddSubmit}>Submit</Button>
```